# jquery stickynav disable when browser size is less than 500 syntax

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have two conditions met for stickynav to trigger and not having much luck. I'm a designer not schooled in jquery language but can fiddle.

here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var aboveHeight = $('header').outerHeight();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight && $(window).width >= 500){
            $('nav').addClass('fixed').css('top','0px').next().css('padding-top','200px');
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('fixed').css('top','60px').next().css('padding-top','200px');
        }
    });
});
```

NEVERMIND... I fixted it all by my lonesome. trial and error.

The syntax was wrong (of course) it should have been

$(window).width() > 500, couldn't answer my own question within 8 hours so posted an edit. hope yall don't mind.

Comment: what exactly u want...

Comment: I would like the scrollTop aboveHeight and the window/screen width to be met before the addClass executes